# Euler Project #520, making current code more efficient for finding simber integers?

Tags: performance, wolfram-mathematica, processing-efficiency

Recently, for my Computer Algebra Systems class to work on. I have been given a problem randomly assigned from Project Euler to solve (Problem 520). The question goes as follows:

> "We define a *simber* to be a positive integer in which any odd digit,
>   if present, occurs an odd number of times, and any even digit, if
>   present, occurs an even number of times.
>
> For example, 141221242 is a 9-digit simber because it has three 1's,
>   four 2's and two 4's.
>
> Let Q(*n*) be the count of all simbers with at most *n* digits.
>
> You are given Q(7) = 287975 and Q(100) mod 1 000 000 123 = 123864868.
>
> Find (∑1≤u≤39 Q(2^u)) mod 1 000 000 123."

The class requires me to use Wolfram-Mathematica to solve the problem using efficient coding. The code below is what my function of Q(*n*). I've included comments to help navigate through my coding.

```
Q[x_] := (
  s = 0; (*Initalizes simber count*)
  For[i = 1, StringLength[ToString[i]] <= x, 
   i++,(*Starts at 1 and continues until number is no longer 'x' digits long*)
   num = ToString[i]; (*Sets 'num' to 'i' in string form*)
   While[num != "", (*Loops until 'num' string is blank*)
    If[EvenQ[
      ToExpression[
       Characters[num][[
        1]]]], (*If the first digit of 'num' is Even*)
        If[EvenQ[
       StringCount[num, 
        Characters[num][[
         1]]]],  (*Checks if there are an Even quantity of the first digit in the string*)
            num = 
       StringDelete[num, 
        Characters[num][[
         1]]]; (*Removes all digits in the string that is the first digit e.g. 43442421 => 3221*)
            If[num == "", (*If string is blank, increase simber count*)
                s++;
            ]
        ,(*else*)
        num = 
       "" (*If first digit is Even but not and Even quanity sets num to "" to break loop *)
        ]
     ,(*If the first digit of 'num' is Odd*)
        If[OddQ[
       StringCount[num, 
        Characters[num][[
         1]]]], (*Checks if there are an Odd quantity of the first digit in the string*)
        num = StringDelete[num, Characters[num][[1]]];
      (*Removes all digits in the string that is the first digit e.g. 
      3292133 => 2921*)
        If[num == "",(*If string is blank, increase simber count*)
            s++;
        ]
        ,(*else*)
        num = 
       "" (*If first digit is Odd but not and Odd quanity sets num to "" to break loop *)
         ]
     ]
    ]
   ];
  s (*Displays final simber count*)
  )
```

I've tested this code with Q[7] to verify the result as 287975. However, the time to process Q[7] took 6 minutes. As the value of *n* increases, the time to process the code gets exponentially higher.

Any help or recommendations to cut this processing time, or have I approached the Euler Problem from the wrong angle?

Answer (score 2):

First, your code is very, well, bloated. This can be written down easier

```
isSimber[int_Integer] := isSimber[IntegerDigits[int]];
isSimber[digits_List] := And @@ Equal @@@ EvenQ[Tally[digits]]
q[n_] := Count[isSimber /@ Range[0, 10^n - 1], True]

q[7] // Timing
(* {58.328, 287975} *)
```

Second, yes I believe you need to think about this further. Just look that you, with your approach, would need to iterate to a number with 2^39 digits. Look that a simple `Do` loop with `u` being **only** 3 takes already 21s. And absolutely nothing is happening there, let alone a computation:

```
Do[
  x = i,
  {i, 10^(2^3)}
  ] // Timing
```

And we haven't even started to think about the memory. So yes, your current approach will not work.